# How would I take 2 columns of data and convert them into a frequency count matrix in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, pivot-table

Say I have 2 columns of data with N unique values in column 1 and M unique values in column 2. I want to convert this to an N x M matrix, where the values of each entry in the matrix is the count of the occurrence of that combination.

For example here's some dummy data:

```
days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Monday','Tuesday','Tuesday','Monday']
weather = ['Rain','Sun','Sun','Sun','Rain','Rain']
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':days,'weather':weather})
```

What I would want in this case since there are 2 unique days and 2 unique weather conditions, would be a 2x2 matrix where the index has "Monday" and "Tuesday", the columns are "Rain" and "Sun", and the values of the matrix in this case would be:

```
[[2,1],
 [1,2]]
```

Because it rained twice on Monday, was Sunny once on Monday, rained once on Tuesday, and was sunny twice on Tuesday. Of course I'd like to be able to do this programmatically for cases where each of the columns have more than 2 distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for a pivot table, for which you could use a custom function to get the len() of items in each cell.

```
days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Monday','Tuesday','Tuesday','Monday']
weather = ['Rain','Sun','Sun','Sun','Rain','Rain']
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':days,'weather':weather})


df.pivot_table(index='day',columns='weather', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x))
```

Output

```
weather  Rain  Sun
day               
Monday      2    1
Tuesday     1    2
```

and if you just want the array

```
df.pivot_table(index='day',columns='weather', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x)).values
```